# Is there any way to change the timing on a html5 text track?

Tags: html, html5-video

If I have subtitles that are not perfectly in sync with the video, is there some way to tell the html5 text track to change the timing?

Thanks.

EDIT: I am talking about html5 subtitles like: `<video><track/></video>`

Also I can do this server side without issue but I want to know if there is a browser side solution.

Comment: Maybe you can provide some more information? Which format do you use? Code?

Comment: Ohhh I thought html5 subtitles were always vtt but I guess maybe I'm wrong. I am doing this on a Chromecast so really I just need any functionality that Chrome might support. Not sure what code to add, it is just a `<track>` tag inside a `<video>` tag. I can definitely handle this server side, but was wanting to check if there is a browser side solution.

Comment: Somehow WebVVT is the standard format beside several other formats - but I didn't want to guess ;-) The `<track>` element is a child of the video element. One attribute defines the source vvt file:
`<track src="subtitles.vtt" kind="subtitles" srclang="en" label="English" />` 

And in the file you can do something like that:

`1
00:00:01.000 --> 00:00:10.000
This is the first line of text, displaying from 1-10 seconds`

Comment: Thanks I know how to write WebVTT files but I'm wondering if there is a way with html5 to change the timing of the file, other than rewriting the whole file, because I can do that server side easily.

Comment: Ah, sorry - my fault. You can manipulate your cues with JavaScript. This is a bit hacky but cues do have a `startTime` and an `endTime` attribute - so this should be easy.

Comment: According to https://w3c.github.io/webvtt/#webvtt-timestamp I highly doubt there is anything native to support this. You will either need to update it client-side with JS or server side.

Comment: You can gets some useful info at this article: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/track/basics/ .. and maybe you could `offset` the `starttime` and `endtime` that comes from the `TextTrackCue` object with JS .. http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-video-element.html#texttrackcue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is "no".

But you can simply modify (in flight) subtitle timestamps to achieve that.